# Is there a way to retrieve the version of the ArcMap Addins currently loaded?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, add-in

The Addin system doesn't seem to be perfect. When I update the Addin in the network share, the version number immediately gets updated in the ArcMap Addin Manager, even though the updated binaries have not been loaded into the Assembly Cache. This can confuse people whether they have the most current version actually loaded.

I am trying to compare the version of the actual binary, to the version ArcMap thinks it has installed. Getting the binary version is easy, but I am having difficulty getting the ArcMap Addin version. Is there an interface for this I need to query? Or is this even possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try `ThisAddin.Version`.

Explanation: Assuming you used the VS add-in template, there should be a class called `ThisAddin` in your add-in's default namespace that has a static `Version` property corresponding to the `Version` element in the `Config.esriaddinx` file. This class is defined in the `Config.Designer.cs` file.

Comment: That is still tied in with the binary itself, so when ArcMap "sees" the new one. The code can't "see" the new one until an ArcMap restart. I'll post a screen shot of the variable I am looking for in a few.

Comment: Sounds like a bug then, as it's supposed to grab the latest version at startup if you're using the shared folder feature. I doubt the version number displayed in the Add-in Manager is exposed anywhere. Seems like anything a developer could to work around this would be hacky. Confirm the problem with support and advise your users about it.